# get child grid data by clicking parent grid row's chceckbox in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am new to kendo. what should i do to get data of child grid by clicking on checkbox on parent grid row. i want whichever parent grid record's checkbox are check that grid's  child grid records.

[image about the grid[parent]and child grid[which shows the deatil record]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7YiU.png)

enter image description here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
                            },
                            pageSize: 6,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverSorting: true
                        },
                        height: 600,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        detailInit: detailInit,
                        dataBound: function() {
                            this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
                        },
                        columns: [{ template: "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' />", width:40},
                            {
                                field: "FirstName",
                                title: "First Name",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "LastName",
                                title: "Last Name",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Country",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "City",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Title"
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });

                function detailInit(e) {
                    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                            },
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverSorting: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            pageSize: 10,
                            filter: { field: "EmployeeID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.EmployeeID }
                        },
                        scrollable: false,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        columns: [
                            { field: "OrderID", width: "110px" },
                            { field: "ShipCountry", title:"Ship Country", width: "110px" },
                            { field: "ShipAddress", title:"Ship Address" },
                            { field: "ShipName", title: "Ship Name", width: "300px" }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your checkbox onClick event handler:

```
click: function(e) {
        var childGrid = this.element.closest("[data-role=grid]").getKendoGrid();
        //and here is data
        var data = childGrid.datasource.data();
    }
```